# Exactly what error is returned by PostgreSQL `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` when a selected row cannot be locked immediately?

Tags: postgresql, select, locking

The [PostgreSQL 9.4 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) states that adding the `NOWAIT` option to a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` means an error is generated when a row cannot be locked:

> To prevent the operation from waiting for other transactions to commit, use the NOWAIT option. With NOWAIT, the statement reports an error, rather than waiting, if a selected row cannot be locked immediately.

**Exactly what error would that be?**

As this is an acceptable condition, I want my Java code to check for such an expected error and then work around it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## SQLState: `55P03`

In Postgres 9.4.x I tested this by performing an unresolved `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in pgAdmin and then doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` in my Java app. I used the JDBC driver `JDBC41 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1201`.

The result was the following [PostgreSQL Error Code](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

- Message:
  `ERROR: could not obtain lock on row in relation "my_table_"`
- Class:
  `Class 55 — Object Not In Prerequisite State`
- SQLState:
  `55P03`
- Condition Name:
  `lock_not_available`

Comment: Tip: You can use `psql` and just `\set VERBOSITY verbose` first.